# iOS 5 javascript events not bubbling

Tags: canvas, svg, ios5

Anyone else seeing JavaScript event issues in the iOS 5 version of UIWebView?

My app has 2 "layers" that cover the screen.  A canvas tag as a background, and an svg shape in the foreground.  Both have events attached to them.

In iOS 4, a touchStart event on the SVG shape would trigger it's event.  Touching outside the shape would bubble the event down to the canvas tag's event handler.

In iOS 5, that is not happening.  Touching on the SVG shape still triggers it's event handler.  Touching outside the shape does nothing, however.  It's not being bubbled up.

Any clue why, or what can be done to fix it?